# Why is Euler's Identity stated the way it is?

Tags: calculus

Ok this is probably the most absurd question you'll ever read, but it came to my mind, and I cant shake it off. Eulers Identity states that:
$e^{i\pi}+1=0$. So my ridiculous question is why was it stated this way? Why couldnt it have been $e^{i\pi}=-1$? Are there any reasons for this, or it could have been either of the two, but this one was chosen?

Comment: Sorry I wasnt sure what to tag this at all, so I chose calculus. Please fix as needed.

Comment: Well, I've seen it stated both ways.

Comment: It's just an aesthetic matter. I prefer the second one, though I think there's not much merit in this "identity" anyhow.

Comment: I would call $e^{i\pi}+1=0$ an ${\it equation}$ and use the term ${\it identity}$ only for equations with a free variable in it, e.g. $e^{i\phi}=\cos(\phi) + i\sin(\phi)$.

Comment: @Yuval: "...there's not much merit..."? Really?

Comment: @Mitch: That's my earnest opinion. How about $e^{i\pi/4} = \sqrt{1/2}(1+i)$?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The reason is to get just the $5$ "fundamental" numbers $\pi,e,i,0,1$ into one equation.